# How to Correctly Authenticate a User Wtih NextJS and Supabase

Tags: next.js13, supabase

I'm following the instructions provided in [Supabase Auth with Next.js Pages](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs-pages#client-side-data-fetching-with-rls)

I don't need to do any server side processing and just need a basic setup up and running on the browser client.

My `pages/auth/signup.js` looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';

const supabase = createClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
  );


const Signup = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
            email: email,
            password: password
          });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div>
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Signup;
```

My `pages/_app.js` looks like this:

```
import { createPagesBrowserClient } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs";
import { SessionContextProvider } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-react";
import { useState } from "react";
import "../styles/global.css";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Create a new supabase browser client on every first render.
  const [supabaseClient] = useState(() => createPagesBrowserClient());
  return (
    <SessionContextProvider
      supabaseClient={supabaseClient}
      initialSession={pageProps.initialSession}
    >
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionContextProvider>
    // <Component {...pageProps} />
    
  );
}
```

Weirdly, signing up worked a few times sporadically and then stopped.

With the pages directory in Next JS (Next.js v13.4.19), what is the correct way in Javascript to:

1. Signup
2. Login
3. Use a signed in user's information to allow access to protected pages.

Comment: If you don't care about doing anything serverside, then you don't need to use the auth-helpers at all. You can just use the plain supabase js client. All you have to do is to make sure all interaction with Supabase happens on the client side. Your sign up logic seems fine.